# gettersで取得したデータをコンポーネント側のdataに追加したい

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Storeで管理しているデータをgettersで取得し、
コンポーネント側のdataに追加したいと思っています。

現在以下のようにソースを書いているのですが全く表示がされません。

dataは https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com から取得したデータになるのですが、
あらかじめstoreのdataに手動で値を入れておけば問題なく表示ができるのですが、
apiを利用したデータは表示することができません。

どなたかどうすれば良いかわかる方がいらっしゃればご教授いただけますと幸いです。

※またteratailでも同様の質問( https://teratail.com/questions/352240 )をしています。
どちらかで解決ができればその旨を追記致します。

#### ソースコード

```js
// store/index.js

import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

export default createStore({
    
    state : {
        
        isLoading : true,
        data      : ""
        
    },
    
    getters : {
        
        isLoading : (state) => state.isLoading,
        data      : (state) => state.data
        
    },
    
    mutations : {
        
        setData(state, { data }){
            
            state.data = data
            
        }
        
    },
    
    actions : {
        
        async fetchData({ commit, state }){
            
            const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1`;
            const rowData = await axios.get(url)
            const data = rowData.data
            
            state.isLoading = false
            
            commit('setData', { data })
            
        }
    }
    
})
```

```
// App.vue

<template>
  <div>

    <template v-if="isLoading">
      <p>Loading...</p>
    </template>

    <template v-else>
      {{ data }}
    </template>


  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {

  data(){
    return {

      data : this.$store.getters.data

    }
  },

  created(){

    this.fetchData();

  },

  computed : {

    ...mapGetters([ 'isLoading' ])

  },

  methods : {

    ...mapActions([ 'fetchData' ])

  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/352240) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: 他のサイトでも同じ質問する場合は、その旨を記載した方が良いのですね。
ご提案ありがとうございます！

Comment: store経由で更新を受け取る場合はcomputedで参照するのが一般的です。特別 `data()` で扱いたい理由がなければ `...mapGetters([ 'isLoading', 'data' ])` で更新参照できるはずです